# What are the pigments in my orchid?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, orchids

This orchid has been with me for one week. I don't know if she's ok, she has little points on her flowers and her stalk isn't brown at all. I watered the plant the same day I bought her and yesterday. She's in a garden with a ceiling but the sun enters in the sides.

*Click on the pictures for larger view.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not clear where the problem is. Has the color of the blossoms changed from when you brought it home?

Comment: @michelle yes, it was all white and violet. It doesn't have the brown/yellow pigments in the petal

Comment: What season is it, and did you get direct sunlight on it? And was it raised indoor but you put it outside? Just wondering if it got burnt.